# ng-swipe-right defaults to toggle switch on left

Tags: angularjs

I have following label in angular js application:

```
<label data-ng-swipe-right="x = true"
                       data-ng-swipe-left="x = false"
                       data-ng-click="x = !x"></label>
```

The output I get is a toggle switch is always on left. Is there a way to default the toggle to right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label ng-init="x = true" data-ng-swipe-right="x = true" data-ng-swipe-left="x = false" data-ng-click="x = !x"></label>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Sorry for late response.